# Ruby on rails KeyError environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, environment-variables, development-environment

I experience an error : `'fetch': key not found: "APPLICATION_HOST" (KeyError)'`

This errors occurres since I tried to implement a new gem that requires `dotenv` gem. That produced a lot of tries to fix. I revert my code to a stable one but I still cannot run my app supposed related to my machine configuration.

For now none of my environment variables in my .env file can be read by the app.

A teammate has the same code as mine and hasn't any config in his `~/.bashrc` neither in `~/.bash_profile`and our `.env` file has chown readable states.

Last information we use a gemset for this project.

Thanks by advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by cloning the repo in another folder and the project runs again!